# Facebook accepts more than one password

Tags: facebook

With Facebook login, my password had a form of uppercase letters, lowercase letter and numbers. Not strong, but it did the job. For example

```
hunTer2
```

Recently, I was told by an acquaintance that I could do these as well

```
HunTer2
HUNtER2
```

I have tried other combinations but they do not seem to work. Is there a reason Facebook allows these alternative passwords?

Comment: +1 For "hunter2". http://www.bash.org/?244321

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's because of <kbd>caps lock</kbd> `key on/off` to prevent double entering password.

Per http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-passwords-are-not-case-sensitive-update/3612

> Facebook actually accepts **three** forms of your password:
>
> 1. Your original password.
> 2. Your original password with the first letter capitalized. This is only for mobile devices, which sometimes capitalize the first character of a word.
> 3. Your original password with the case reversed, for those with a caps lock key on.
>
> The third case is the one I stumbled upon today. Wolens told me Facebook has had this implemented “for a while” although he couldn’t say for exactly how long. He also noted that Facebook doesn’t believe this impact the security of the user’s passwords, since the characters are still unique, just flipped.

Comment: Which is an enormous real-world problem, which I can attest to after having seen our support department deal with many issues related to this since our platform moved to case-sensitive passwords.

Comment: @larson4 which could be OK, provided they store three hashes and never the original password to modify. I'd assume they store three hashes of the three forms of the password, per http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: @JeffAtwood: You only have to store one hash.  Then compute three hashes for the password the user submits.  If one of them matches, it's OK.

Comment: @jeff I was not involved in the implementation, and was not aware of this technique.  But then, though I am working on reading the entire Internet, I hadn't reached this Coding Horror post yet.

Comment: @larson4 - Waitasecond.  Your platform didn't have case-sensitive passwords before?

Comment: @kevin in ancient times, the last millenium.  and it is a platform based on the IBM AS/400, which still has case insensitive passwords by default.

Comment: Ok, according to your description `hUnter2` should not work!?

Comment: vote up and glad to meet you here.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook also accept one more password type.

> Your current password + any single character

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: You can verify it by logging into your Facebook account. If your Facebook account password is "Password" then try "Password1" "Password@" etc.

Comment: I don't have source of it but I think they made this feature to provide better user experience.

Comment: I am a source -- I just found this out myself by mistake. Still working as of today.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?[2]
I can login on fb with 2 passwords and they differ with only 1 letter at the end (second password is first pass + 1 letter that I set). But I can't just put any other character after first password and login, it only works with the one I set before.